# Tag Merge Requests: [request(s)] ---> [http-request]

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

These two tags: [request](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/request) (62 questions) and <s>its twin</s> [requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requests) (19 questions) have [ambiguous meaning](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). It can means *certificate request, HTTP request* or perhaps *my boss request*.

*Almost* all question refer to one specific request, i.e. HTTP-request. So I suggest that we *renamed* [request](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/request) and [requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/requests) to [http-request](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-request), then burn these two meta-tags.

*NB: **I've cleaned-up these tags** so they don't contain the question which not related to HTTP request, for example: [MySQL Server : Most Frequent Requests](https://serverfault.com/questions/186207/mysql-server-most-frequent-requests)*

Comment: Bonus question for mod ♦: What's the difference between **synonym** and **merge** action?

Comment: Synonyms and merges are two sides of the same coin. A merge is a one off action. A synonym automatically re tags a tag when it is used.

Comment: Thanks @MarkHenderson. For clarification: suppose I have two tags [tag-a] and [tag-b]. If mod ♦ perform **merge [tag-a] to [tag-b]**, did [tag-b] get deleted and not listed on [this page](http://serverfault.com/tags) again ?